# Заполнение нечётных элементов одномерного массива рандомными числами,а чётных - нулями

Tags: c++, массивы

Мне нужно создать одномерный массив который будет заполнен так: нечётные элементы - рандомные числа(желательно чтобы они не повторялись), а чётные - нулями. Как создать массив заполненный нулями или же заполненный рандомными числами понятно, не могу понять как после заполнения массива нулям(или ранд.числами) обойти массив так, чтобы нечётные элементы заполнились хоть как-то, не говоря уже про рандомный диапазон чисел без повторений.

Comment: Что получилось до сих пор?

Comment: Проверяйте индекс на четность. `for (i = 0;...) if (i & 1) a[i] = random(); else a[i] = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

```
int v[size] = {}; // забиваем всё нулями
for (int i=0; i<size; i+=2) { // шаг — двойка
    v[i] = rnd(); // 0,2,4... заполняем случайными числами
}
```

Чтобы избежать повторений, берем нарастающую последовательность и перемешиваем её. Потом можно аналогично примеру выше обнулить нужные элементы.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь